# SQL Stopped Recognizing Temp Table in Seperate Stored Proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

EDIT: The issue turned out to be a line I didn't include - select * from pbiMaster. We don't know why/when it was added, but it was of course erroring out and I didn't notice it. But notably, it wasn't a scope issue.

I have a query that has been working but is now failing due to invalid object, which is a temporary table that doesn't exist.

The error occurs in a stored procedure called by the query.

The query checks for the temp table, drops it if it exists, then creates the table, then calls the stored proc that uses the table.

The error is that the stored proc can no longer find the temp table

This is that portion of the main query...

```
if object_id('tempdb..#PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_ReportRows') is not null drop table 
#PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_ReportRows
CREATE TABLE #PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_ReportRows (Period int, Org nvarchar(10)
            , TotalARBalance decimal(19,5), TotalAROver90 decimal(19,5), PctOver90 
            decimal(19,5), TotalRetainage decimal(19,5)
            , JTDUnbilled decimal(19,5)
            , TotalRevenue decimal(19,5), DailyAvgRevenue decimal(19,5)
            , DaysOut decimal(19,5))

EXEC spGSP_PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_UnbilledRevenue
```

This is the only reference to the temp table in the stored proc and is where the error occurs...

```
UPDATE pbiMaster
SET pbiMaster.TotalRevenue = Coalesce(grossRev.TotalRevenue, 0), 
pbiMaster.DailyAvgRevenue = Coalesce(grossRev.DailyAvg, 0)
FROM #PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_ReportRows as pbiMaster
left join #SP_PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_GrossRev_90SumsFromReportRows grossRev on 
pbiMaster.Period = grossRev.Period and pbiMaster.Org = grossRev.Org
```

I've included the code for reference, but I don't think it matters. The code hasn't changed. The only thing I can think of that may have caused things to stop working is that I ran the main query with the calls to the proc commented out. After that, the temp table could not be found.

Any ideas on why this started happening? If I call the temp table from anywhere outside of the main query, it fails.

Comment: Do you realize that `#PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_ReportRows` and `##PBI_MktFinSum_ARDaysOut_ReportRows` are different objects? The former is a local temp table specific to the current connection, the latter is a global temp table that (within limits) can be shared between connections.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This is a mistake in my post - the global in the stored proc is me playing around and was never executed. I'm removing it from the post. Good catch though.